# Phonegap run script only once on startup

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, mobile

I'm currently making an application in PhoneGap, and i want to run a script only ONCE, just when starting the app.

I tried using the "ondeviceready" function, but this one executes every time I return to that main page of my application...

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use PhoneGap LocalStorage, store some key with value like 0 or 1 to indicate whether user came first time to main page or not, depending on that execute your script.

Comment: I was also thinking about that, but the next time the app starts, wont the value still be "1", making this solution only work the first time after installing the application?